# how to make angular 2 file compilation in separate folder

Tags: angular, typescript

How should i make my type-script files to be get compile in app folder in angular 2. My working directory is dev.

I want to keep separate js and ts files.

What changes i need to perform in index.html file or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tsconfig.json file if you don't have one yet. Then set `compilerOptions` property `outDir` to `./app`.